# Remove columns which has the exact same values as other columns

Tags: r, correlation

I have an issue where I have a large dataframe (29784 rows x 584 columns), where some of the columns have the exact same as other columns. I would like to find a smart way of getting rid of the columns that have the exact same values as other columns and only keep one of the columns.

[image]

I am relatively inexperienced with R, but I have tried the following solution:

Start by creating a correlation matrix, set the upper triangle and the diagonal to zero, and then remove the rows with

```
##### Obtaining correlation matrix:
mCorrelation <- cor(mData)

##### Removing columns that are highly correlated
cor_matrix_remove <- mCorrelation 
cor_matrix_remove [upper.tri(cor_matrix_remove )] <- 0
diag(cor_matrix_remove ) <- 0

mData <- mData[,!apply(cor_matrix_remove , 2, function(x) any(x > 0.999))]
```

However, the issue is that all columns are removed, so I do not have the first distinct column left.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do something like: `mData |> cor() |> as.data.frame() |> tibble::rownames_to_column() |> tidyr::pivot_longer(-rowname) |> dplyr::filter(value == 1 | value == -1, rowname != name)`. That will show you the variables that are perfectly correlated.

Answer (score 2):

```
df1 <- df[!duplicated(as.list(df))]
```

Will this work?